# Why i get client & server side output for same JSP method?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have seen the method out.write() takes an int as well as a string., The problem is when i pass a int it doesn't display at the client side or server side.,( i don't know the exact server side in net beans). And when i pass a String it displays in the client side. My problem is Why creators of the write class, develope that method, int for server side display and string for client side display.... OR am i wrong.., please help.., i will attach the code below.,

```
</head>
<body>

    <% 
    int abc=10;

    out.write(abc);//server side
    out.write(""+abc);//client side
    out.write("<br>");
    out.write(abc);//server side
    out.write("<br>");
    out.write(abc*2);//server side
    out.write("<br>");
    out.write(abc*3);//server side
    out.println("<h1>"+(abc*abc)+"<br>");//client side

    %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're writing raw bytes when you pass an int. Your client receives them, but they're unprintable.

Comment: What do you mean by *server side* and *client side* in your current code? Everything will be executed at server side because is scriptlet (which usage you should avoid).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if we pass an int.., where it gets printed, at the server side ?? if server side, where can we see it in netbeans?

Comment: The same output stream everything is written to. It's written to the client. But the characters aren't printable.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch okay i got it, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, all of your output is being sent to the client. When you use `out` in a scriptlet you are getting a [`JspWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html) which is further a [`java.io.Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) when you call [`out.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28int%29) per the javadoc -

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

So, you are writing characters with the integer values 10, 20 and 30. The ASCII table defines 10 as linefeed, 20 as (device control 4) and 30 as (record separator). None of those will display correctly when embedded in your HTML and rendered in a browser. Lowercase 'a' is 97 and 'a' **is** *printable*, so if you had

```
int abc='a';      // 97 - because ASCII 
out.write(abc++); // 'a', then increment to 'b'
out.write(abc++); // 'b', then increment to 'c'
out.write(abc++); // 'c', then increment to 'd'
System.out.println((char) abc); // <-- 'd' on the server.
```

If you want output on the server you should probably use (and configure) a logger

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
logger.info((char) abc); // <-- 'd' in the server log (assuming info or up)
```

Finally, I urge you to avoid scriptlets.